# Why has DNS Stopped Working for new CNAME and TXT records

Tags: ubuntu, bind, cname-record, dns-zone

None of the new CNAME and TXT records I add (through VestaCP) are working.

My DNS server has been working fine. Got about 30 domains on it, used to be able to create these records and a few hours later they would be working.

But now, no joy. Add records, **a few days later,** still nothing.

What I can see it that those records by VestaCP are writen to an `example.org.db` file which is then included in `/etc/bind/named.conf`:

`zone "example.org" {type master; file "/path/to/example.org.db";};`

How do I troubleshoot this? I've tried, but so far haven't figured it out.

Should add that I'm checking that these records can be found through [mxtoolbox.com](http://mxtoolbox.com/SuperTool.aspx)

**EDIT**:

The domain name is: cedarvale.org

Example Records:

```
_amazonses.cedarvale.org        14400   IN      TXT             tP8Ni9mnCdomIpnVvx0eYyD//GxCTVXO3XslbmgrcQ0=
unn3jseoejfwzgh2p7oqfh76nlftl42f._domainkey.cedarvale.org       14400   IN      CNAME           unn3jseoejfwzgh2p7oqfh76nlftl42f.dkim.amazonses.com.
```

Comment: I assume you made an error formatting the record and those should be two separate lines?

Answer (score 2):

In a DNS zone file shorthand a resource record without a trailing <kbd>.</kbd> is appended with the `$ORIGIN` (typically the name of the zone).

The host `_amazonses.cedarvale.org` you have added then effectively becomes `_amazonses.cedarvale.org.cedarvale.org.`

That may not be the only problem though, as I can't resolve that record either and  I noticed that ns2.emanwebdesign.com. is not responding at all.

Answer (score 2):

Your nameserver setup is broken. I [ran your zone through DNScheck](http://dnscheck.iis.se/?time=1456232925&id=5482404&view=basic&test=standard); it shows that one of your nameservers isn't responding at all, and the other one has a difference of opinion with the root servers as to which servers should be authoritative for your domain. Once you've fixed this, you can have a look at specific records.